Missing jammy folder nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com
Hello Ubuntu Community,
I am encountering an issue while trying to update my APT cache and install packages on my Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) system. The update process fails with the following error messages:
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Ign:2 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:6 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:8 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.

Could someone from the Canonical team look into the availability of the http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu repositories? Is there an official alternative we should be using?
Thank you for your assistance.
Best regards,
Andy T.

Change to a working mirror using any of the methods explained in the duplicate. Mirrors are volunteers -- keeping them up to date is the job of the mirror admin (not Canonical)

Thanks @user535733 I changed to another mirror and thanks for the explanations about mirror maintanance!
